# Вызвать правильно Jquery плагин wordpress. Ошибка в структуре меню

Tags: wordpress

При отключении стандартного jquery в плагине (`wp_deregister`) и подключении из директории плагина не правильно начинает работать внешний вид>меню - не редактируется структура меню, не работает событие `drop`. При комментировании строчки `wp_deregister` меню работает, а jquery, написанный в плагине перестает функционировать:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function.

Так как же быть? Джедаи wordpress, направьте пожалуйста на путь к решению.

```
function name_func() {
$jquery_latest_version = '1.12.1';
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script('jquery', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/jquery/' . $jquery_latest_version . '/jquery-' . $jquery_latest_version . '.min.js', array(), $jquery_latest_version, false);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
if (is_admin()) {
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'name_func'); //подключаем библиотеки js
}
```

Answer (score 1):

не совсем изящно, но может кому поможет справиться с аналогичной проблемой

```
function name_func($hook) 
{
$jquery_latest_version = '1.12.1';
  if ($hook=="post.php" or $hook=="edit.php") 
  {
  wp_deregister_script('jquery');

  wp_register_script('jquery', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/jquery/' . $jquery_latest_version . '/jquery-' . $jquery_latest_version . '.min.js', array(), $jquery_latest_version, false);
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

  }
}
if (is_admin())
{
  add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'name_func'); //подключаем библиотеки js
}
```